# logstash grok filter ignore certain parts of message

Tags: logstash, syslog, grok

I have a drupal watchdog log file that starts with `syslog` things like timestamp etc, and then has a pipe delimited number of things that I logged in watchdog. Now I am writing a grok filter rule to get fields out of that.

I have a few URLs in the message body so I use `%{URI:request}` for instance to get those. however that creates a field named `port` that is always null and I don't want to throw a lot of empty fields into my elasticsearch DB so I was wodnering how I could get rid of that empty array that looks like this : `"port": [null, null, null]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to unconditionally drop a field, just add a `remove_field => ['port']` to you `grok` block.

If you want to conditionally remove something, you can use either a `ruby` filter to check what is in the field before removing it, or use an `if` around a `mutate { remove_field => ['port'] }` filter.